# Can I apply Bootstrap's Accordion or Alert styles to HTML <details> and <summary>?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, html-tag-details

My projects use Bootstrap and most of the time without any Javascript because I only need the styling. Now I have a project that needs something like their [Accordion](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/) which needs Javascript to work. However there is a standard [`<details>` HTML tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) that can do that. **The problem** is I cannot really apply Accordion styling to it.

This is my best attempt so far but the `accordion-header` simply wraps all the body as well:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="accordion">
    <details class="accordion-item">
        <summary class="">
            <div class="accordion-header">
                Title
            </div>
        </summary>

        <div class="accordion-body">
            <p>This is the body</p>
        </div>
    </details>
</div>
```

An alternative would be somehow making the `summary` look like an `.alert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you meant by the header wrapping the body, but putting the `accordion-button` class on the title element gets you close. The icon doesn't flip, though. That would require JavaScript or a custom CSS solution.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="accordion m-4">
  <details class="accordion-item">
    <summary class="accordion-button">
      <div class="accordion-header">
        Title
      </div>
    </summary>

    <div class="accordion-body">
      <p>This is the body</p>
    </div>
  </details>
</div>
```

---

For Bootstrap 5.2+ where [Accordion CSS variables are supported](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/accordion/#variables), you can add these CSS so the arrow changes as user opens/closes it:

```css
details.accordion-item:not([open]) .accordion-button {
    background-color: var(--bs-accordion-bg);
}

details.accordion-item:not([open]) .accordion-button::after {
    background-image: var(--bs-accordion-btn-active-icon);
    transform: unset;
}

details.accordion-item[open] .accordion-button::after {
    background-image: var(--bs-accordion-btn-icon);
    transform: var(--bs-accordion-btn-icon-transform);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="accordion m-4">
  <details class="accordion-item">
    <summary class="accordion-button">
      <div class="accordion-header">
        Title
      </div>
    </summary>

    <div class="accordion-body">
      <p>This is the body</p>
    </div>
  </details>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thank you very much this is very helpful. I found out a simple CSS for Bootstrap 5.2+ to toggle the arrow. I hope you are okay with me editing your answer to add it.